# Need a query to retrieve complete graph

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

I am trying to retrieve all the node and properties details in parent-child hierarchy.
Nested within each other.
Since I am new with gremlin, graphDB I am having really tough time to get it done.

Please suggest a solution and if you could walk me through it, it will be great.

Following is my structure
[image]

And I am trying to keep the response as clean as possible.
I am using cosmosDB and Gremlin.
NET api for this.

I tried the following but it gave me response in key value,
g.V("some_id").repeat(out()).emit().tree().path()
g.V("some_id").emit().repeat(both().simplePath()).dedup()

please any kind of suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I"m not sure what format you want your result, but use of `path()`, `tree()` or `subgraph()` would typically give you the graph structure. Since you are using CosmosDB, you're only options are `path()` and `tree()` as `subgraph()` [does not appear to be supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-support).

Using this sample graph as a simple tree:

```
g.addV().property(id, '1').as('1').
  addV().property(id, '2a').as('2a').
  addV().property(id, '2b').as('2b').
  addV().property(id, '3a').as('3a').
  addV().property(id, '4a').as('4a').
  addE('child').from('1').to('2a').
  addE('child').from('1').to('2b').
  addE('child').from('2a').to('3a').
  addE('child').from('3a').to('4a')
```

you can see the effect of `path()` which basically gathers the contents of each step Gremlin took:

```
gremlin> g.V('1').repeat(out()).emit().path()
==>[v[1],v[2a]]
==>[v[1],v[2b]]
==>[v[1],v[2a],v[3a]]
==>[v[1],v[2a],v[3a],v[4a]]
```

Since I used `out()` we don't see the edges, but that is easily remedied by adding making a small adjustment to directly consume edges into the path history:

```
gremlin> g.V('1').repeat(outE().inV()).emit().path()
==>[v[1],e[0][1-child->2a],v[2a]]
==>[v[1],e[1][1-child->2b],v[2b]]
==>[v[1],e[0][1-child->2a],v[2a],e[2][2a-child->3a],v[3a]]
==>[v[1],e[0][1-child->2a],v[2a],e[2][2a-child->3a],v[3a],e[3][3a-child->4a],v[4a]]
```

Taken together with duplication removed on your application side you have a complete graph with `path()`.

Replacing `path()` with `tree()` will essentially do that deduplication by maintaining the tree structure of the path history:

```
gremlin> g.V('1').repeat(out()).emit().tree()
==>[v[1]:[v[2b]:[],v[2a]:[v[3a]:[v[4a]:[]]]]]
gremlin> g.V('1').repeat(outE().inV()).emit().tree()
==>[v[1]:[e[0][1-child->2a]:[v[2a]:[e[2][2a-child->3a]:[v[3a]:[e[3][3a-child->4a]:[v[4a]:[]]]]]],e[1][1-child->2b]:[v[2b]:[]]]]
```

The `Tree` is just represented as a `Map` where each key represents a like a root and value is another `Tree` (i.e. the branches from it). It is perhaps better visualized this way:

```
gremlin> g.V('1').repeat(out()).emit().tree().unfold()
==>v[1]={v[2b]={}, v[2a]={v[3a]={v[4a]={}}}}
gremlin> g.V('1').repeat(out()).emit().tree().unfold().next().value
==>v[2b]={}
==>v[2a]={v[3a]={v[4a]={}}}
```

If neither of these structures are suitable and `subgraph()` is not available you can technically just capture and return the edges you traverse as the low level elements of your subgraph as [described in this blog post](https://stephen.genoprime.com/snippet/2020/08/01/snippet-12.html).

Given the comments on this answer I also present the following option which used `group()`:

```
gremlin> g.V('1').emit().
......1>   repeat(outE().group('a').by(outV()).by(inV().fold()).inV()).cap('a').unfold()
==>v[1]=[v[2a], v[2b]]
==>v[3a]=[v[4a]]
==>v[2a]=[v[3a]]
```

It's not exactly a "tree" but if you know the root (in this case `v[1]`) you can find its key in the `Map`. The values are the children. You can then look up each of those keys in the `Map` to find if they have children and so on. For example, we can lookup `v[2b]` and find that it has no children while looking up `[v2a]` reveals a single child of `[v3a]`. Gremlin can be pretty flexible in getting answers if you can be sorta flexible in how you deal with the results.

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you so much for the post, before I could run it I wanted to know one thing about traversing the graph is that, can we capture the response. I have tried once to use project('property1','property2'..).by('property1').property('2'). 
this gives me flatten json as response.  Can I use similar thing while traversing, selecting the property I need from a vertex and having it as an object. 

{
  firstVertex:{
     properties
    subVertex : {
                          properties ,
                          and so on..

                        }
 }
}

Comment: Also Stephen, I wanted to know cant we structure the response as parent-child, key-value from the gremlin result itself. Or is it something which I need to do in my dotnet application.
The closest thing which I got was using tree(), because using path() I get multiple vertex in the first level of json object. I might be wrong, please advice . Main requirement is to read the complete graph and parse it and share it with UI which is going to bind it into a tree structure. 
Is it possible to achieve it ?

Comment: yes, you can apply `project()` to `path()`/`tree()` by adding a `by()` modulator to either like, `path().by(project(...)...)`.  Please see the TinkerPop documentation for how `by()` gets applied with those steps. If you want to maintain parent-child relationships in a singular fashion then `tree()` is probably your only option built into Gremlin aside from `subgraph()` which you can't use.

Comment: If you knew  the depth of your tree you could `project()` each level of it with a nested query to get the exact structure you want, but there really isn't a way to use `repeat()` to do that dynamically. I updated my answer for one more option you could consider. maybe that will work for you.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, project did the magic. Though its taking too much of request charge on Azure, I don't know how to optimise it. I am still learning, hopefully I will optimise it later some day.